# Where are the certificates of ca's stored in firefox?

Tags: firefox, certificate, x509certificate

I want to copy all the ca certificates of firefox to my a folder or a keystore. I don't want to export the certificates one by one. It will take a lot of time. But I am not able to get the **directory** where the ca certificates are stored. I am using windows xp.
 Where will I be able to see the certificates or the keystore containing the certificates of the firefox browser?
**From the answers below,**
 I have come to know that the certificates are stored in th ecert8.db file. but how to extract the contents of this file? The reason I am asking this is that my application requires that when a client submits his certificate, I have to see if the issuer is a valid ca. For that I need a list of the valid ca's. So is there any way I can anagrammatically access the certificates in cert8.db and verify the client certifiate.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the certificates are stored in cert8.db under your profiles folder.

For Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>
```

[Source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)

Comment: Is it possible to extract certificates from that file?

Comment: cert8.db is not a sqlite file. The addon is not ableto open that file.

Comment: This is the tool to view the certificates [link](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html) If you need to export the same certificates to another computer/user. Just copy and replace the same file on their computer.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that I want to export the certificate files.I want to see teh files in a folder. I don't want to view them or copy the cert8.db to another computer.